# Why sub SQL in FROM area can't be null?

Tags: oracle

```
select col_1,
       col_2
  from tbl_a A,
       tbl_b B,
       ( select col_1,col_2 from tbl_c where clo_c_1 <> '1' ) C
 where A.col_1 = B.col_1
   and A.col_2 = B.col_2
   and (A.col_2 = B.col_2
    or  C.col_2 = A.col_2);
```

My environment is Oracle,when I run this SQL,if the sub SQL C hasn't got a result,then the entire SQL returns NULL.Whereas if C has a result(not null) which fits other condions,there could be a result.Would somebody explain why sub SQL at the from area need to be not NULL?Thanks very much.

Comment: You are looking for an outer join - which gets a lot easier when you stop using the old and outdated implicit joins in the `where` clause but use an explicit `JOIN` operator (which is recommended by Oracle anyway to do outer joins).

Comment: Got it,I didn't want SQL to be too complicated at that time so didn't think about outer join.This is really a solution.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bring yourself into the 90s and start using standard joins:

```
select col_1,
       col_2
  from tbl_a A
          inner join
       tbl_b B
          on A.col_1 = B.col_1
             and A.col_2 = B.col_2
          left join
       ( select col_1,col_2 from tbl_c where clo_c_1 <> '1' ) C
          on
             C.col_2 = A.col_2
```

As a guess. I'm not entirely sure what your join conditions should be but that's my first attempt.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour. When you join two result sets, you only want to get results where the join criteria is satisfied. If the criteria are not satisfied, you should get no results.

If I run the query "get me all the employees older than 65, and get their departments", if there are no employees older than 65, you would not expect to get any results, even if there are some departments in the database.

```
SELECT emp.name, dept.dept_name
FROM   emp
JOIN   dept
ON     (emp.dept_no = dept.dept_no)
WHERE  emp.age > 65;
```

As the others said, if you actually want to get rows regardless of whether the subquery has any results, you need to use an outer join.